# Cycle.js override image sizes

Tags: responsive-design, jquery-cycle

I am using cycle.js, but the site is responsive.

I'd like to be able to use a large image (big enough for the full screen version) and then use `max-width:100%` on the image to reduce it's width based on the screen size.

Problem is that `cycle.js` overrides with inline styles based on whatever size the image is. So if it's `800x600` then it will always display at that size, regardless of whether the containing div's width is 100px or 1000px

Code:

```
<div id="rightCol">
            <div class="slideshow">
                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-PGEqrdJBKmc/T_xe7hoz0yI/AAAAAAAAA0w/vKDMnf-5p7o/s1600/cat+5.jpg" />
                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-PGEqrdJBKmc/T_xe7hoz0yI/AAAAAAAAA0w/vKDMnf-5p7o/s1600/cat+5.jpg" />
                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-PGEqrdJBKmc/T_xe7hoz0yI/AAAAAAAAA0w/vKDMnf-5p7o/s1600/cat+5.jpg" />
                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-PGEqrdJBKmc/T_xe7hoz0yI/AAAAAAAAA0w/vKDMnf-5p7o/s1600/cat+5.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

## rightCol{

```
width:72.5%;
float:right;
```

}

## slideshow {

```
width:100%
```

}

## slideshow img{

```
max-width:100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the internal working of cycle.js

```
// apparently a lot of people use image slideshows without height/width attributes on the images.
// Cycle 2.50+ requires the sizing info for every slide; this block tries to deal with that.
var requeue = false;
options.requeueAttempts = options.requeueAttempts || 0;
$slides.each(function() {
    // try to get height/width of each slide
    var $el = $(this);
    this.cycleH = (opts.fit && opts.height) ? opts.height : ($el.height() || this.offsetHeight || this.height || $el.attr('height') || 0);
    this.cycleW = (opts.fit && opts.width) ? opts.width : ($el.width() || this.offsetWidth || this.width || $el.attr('width') || 0);

    if ( $el.is('img') ) {
        // sigh..  sniffing, hacking, shrugging...  this crappy hack tries to account for what browsers do when
        // an image is being downloaded and the markup did not include sizing info (height/width attributes);
        // there seems to be some "default" sizes used in this situation
        var loadingIE   = ($.browser.msie  && this.cycleW == 28 && this.cycleH == 30 && !this.complete);
        var loadingFF   = ($.browser.mozilla && this.cycleW == 34 && this.cycleH == 19 && !this.complete);
        var loadingOp   = ($.browser.opera && ((this.cycleW == 42 && this.cycleH == 19) || (this.cycleW == 37 && this.cycleH == 17)) && !this.complete);
```

it needs to get the height width attribute of the image elements. So write a simple helper function in JS which can provide this when the window is resized. Should not be very hard with a little bit of googling.

[jquery cycle automatically fit to window width on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467656/jquery-cycle-automatically-fit-to-window-width-on-resize)

[Jquery Cycle Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082360/jquery-cycle-resize)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a fix for this when I used Cycle.js but needed it to be responsive.

I had to add a transparent dummy.gif image with a fixed width and height before the other images.

e.g.

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">

     <div id="slider">

        <img src="images/dummy.gif" width="960px" height="300px">

        <img  src="images/image1.jpg" />

        <img  src="images/image2.jpg" />

        <img  src="images/image3.jpg" />  

        <img  src="images/image4.jpg" />

    </div>
</div>
```

The css to go with it was:

```
#slider
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:300px;
    max-width:960px;
}
#slider img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; 
}
```

There is an example here: http://jacobhammond.co.uk/ - please note the website is not finished and is kind of just an experiment. I'm currently working on my actual site.